# _popen opens terminal for a split second c++

Tags: c, windows, popen

I have a server/client program. My client uses `_popen` to execute commands. When I send a command from server to client, my client opens a new terminal(cmd) and then closes it. All of this happens within a second.

I don't want my client program to open and close a terminal when executing a command. I don't want any terminal when I execute a command on my client with `_popen`. How can I prevent that my client opens a new terminal?

Client:

```
FILE* f = _popen(command, "r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("error _popen 2\n");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Windows.  This is a feature.  Offhand, since `popen()` spawns a copy of `CMD.EXE`, you might try something like `"/c command"`, where you append the `"/c"` option so `CMD.EXE` sees that and doesn't pop up a console.  It might even work.

Comment: Should I do it like this: strcat(command, " /c");

Comment: Other way around - start the command with `"/c "`, not end it.  Try typing `cmd /?` in a Windows terminal and see what options it presents you with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `popen()` isn't what you need.
Take a look at the `_spawn` family of functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions), maybe that's what you're looking for?

There are also some cross-platform C libraries out there for executing other programs, that already invented the wheel you are trying to reinvent. For example:

- https://github.com/DaanDeMeyer/reproc
- https://github.com/brechtsanders/crossrun